# AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'InputSpec'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am trying to load the bert-language-model:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
import tokenization

folder = "multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12"

config_path = folder+'/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = folder+'/bert_model.ckpt'
vocab_path = folder+'/vocab.txt'

tokenizer =  tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_path, do_lower_case=False)
model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path, training=True)
model.summary()
```

and I got the error:

```
----> 4 model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path, training=True)
```

in *layer_normalization.py* from Anaconda packages:

```
---> 70         self.input_spec = keras.engine.InputSpec(shape=input_shape)

AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'InputSpec'
```

Installed:

```
Tensorflow version Version: 2.7.0
Keras  Version Version: 2.7.0
```

Please help me to sort out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.7 has API `tensorflow.keras.layers.InputSpec`

Replace

```
keras.engine.InputSpec(shape=input_shape)
```

with

```
tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=input_shape)
```